# Why won't this form validate?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

The "onsubmit" statement is not called:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateSearchKeyword()">
        <input class="text_search" id="text_search" name="text_search" type="text" value="search" onfocus="if (this.value=='search') this.value = ''" onBlur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'search'"  />
    </form>
```

This is my validation function:

```
function validateSearchKeyword()
{ alert ('sad');//for testing purposes - this alert is not showed
if (document.getElementById('text_search').value==""){creatediv('divWarnSearch','You must supply a value', '120px', '250px');return false;}
}
```

The function *creatediv* is working great with other forms, so the problem is not that one.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Armadillo, What browser are you testing in? This issue might possibly be caused by the onblur event firing before the onsubmit and refilling the textbox. See RVeur23's answer for more info - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556448/why-wont-this-form-validate/557042#557042

Comment: Ohh god, I was missing the js include. Sorry guys ;)

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a submit button, which may result in users not being able to submit the form in some browsers.

Furthermore, it would be helpful if you could post your validation function, so we can check if there problem is there, e.g. does it return a boolean?

What are you results if you use the following:

```
<form ... onsubmit="alert('Foo'); return true">
```

Comment: Do I really need the submit button to validate it? Because, when the Enter key is pressed, the form is correctly submitted. Thanks

Comment: @Armadillo, And how do you press the Enter key if you happen to be browsing on a device that doesn't have a keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that the function you are calling is actually there, then I'd go through that function to check for problems. Firebug might be of use to you, or you could just go with sticking the following in the top of the called function (to make sure it's getting that far):

```
alert('here');
```

Comment: Firefox's error console will already tell you if the function exists or not, no need for firebug for that.

Comment: Yeah, but I was thinking more along the lines of stepping through the function to look for problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is :

```
onBlur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'search'"
```

When you submit, you lost the focus on the textbox and the event is launched: try to put

```
alert(document.getElementById('text_search').value);
```

and you will get "search" and not empty string...

Comment: Good point, but the onsubmit event fires before the onblur refills the textbox (well, in FF3, IE7 and Chrome it does). The OP should probably update their validation function to ignore the "default" value though, just to be safe across all browsers.

Comment: I'm at the job now and here we are in IE6. Just to be sure, add =='' || =='Search'...

Answer (score -1):

tried `onsubmit="javascript: validateSearchKeyword();"` ? AFAIK, it's already returning, no need to specify that.

You may also try removing the ().

And also, the submit button [as Mr Potato Head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556448/why-wont-this-form-validate/556460#556460) says, if you didn't remove it to make the code terse.

EDIT: This was a badly thought out post. This is a good example of what not to do. If you find any of these suggestions implemented in your code, refactor!

Comment: Actually, it is necessary to use return, as the return type of onsubmit dictates whether or not the form is submitted.

Comment: I mean that if the function already returns inside its body, you'd be calling return twice.

Comment: @Adriano: Exactly: you return once from validateSearchKeyword(), and once from onsubmit.

Comment: Why the downmod? Not angry, would just like to know.
And my comments meant 'I haven't had to do it with 'return function()'

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean it was you, I just asked.

Comment: I didn't -1, but I see why someone did. 1) A 'javascript:' label is COMPLETELY unnecessary, 2) suggesting they remove () is silly, 3) A boolean should be returned from the validation function, which should be returned to the onsubmit event: true to allow the submission to occur, false to abort it.

Comment: Fair enough. I should have thought a bit before posting. Actually, this is a good example of bad practices. Marking it as such.